# Addining record to MySQL db - InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm simply trying to add an record to table1 when hitting submit button (HTTP POST) however I keep getting the below error:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured
> for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the
> 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the
> application service provider. 
> If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also
> ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions
> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for
> DbContext.

IActionResult in controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetTicket(HelpDeskViewModel h)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var db = new HelloDataContext();
        db.table1.Add(new HelpDeskViewModel   //issue appears to happening at this line
        {
        ticketID = h.ticketID,
        category = h.category, 
        description = h.description
        });
        
        db.SaveChanges();        
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Feedback");
}
```

DBContext class:

```cs
public class HelloDataContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUserHelper>
{    
    public HelloDataContext()
    {        
    }
    public DbSet<Quotation> quotation { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HelpDeskViewModel> table1 { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Is this an asp.net mvc project or an asp.net core project?

Comment: You can try to add `public HelloDataContext (DbContextOptions<HelloDataContext > options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }` to your dbcontext.